# How can I display the desired value in ASCII code inputted by me?

Tags: java, ascii

I need Java code. Please help me. Example: when I enter the number in ASCII

```
0 the output will be nul
1 for soh
2 for stx until it reaches the max number of ASCII.
```

Consider this code. It outputs an ASCII number. How can I reverse it?

```
String test = "ABCD";
for ( int i = 0; i < test.length(); ++i ) {
    char c = test.charAt( i );
    int j = (int) c;
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
    public class CharToASCII{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
          BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          System.out.println("Enter the char:");
          String str = buff.readLine();
          for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ){
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            int j = (int) c;// your work is done here
            System.out.println("ASCII OF "+c +" = " + j + ".");
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: @jhoanne you need to make proper imports

Comment: can you reverse the output of this code? instead of enter the char: can you i use enter the ascii code. e.g. (Enter ascii code: 0 char of 0 is NUL

Comment: @jhoanne ya for that you need to convert `int` to `char`

Comment: instead of enter the char: can you i use enter the ascii code. e.g. (Enter ascii code: 41, char of 41 is ) because i can convert int to char. pls help again

Comment: @jhoanne yes you can , I would suggest you to clear fundamentals , It would be trouble for you in future if you just follow this approch

Answer (score 1):

Just cast an integer value to char.:

```
int value = (int) 'a';
System.out.println((char) value);  // prints a
```

---

If you need some literal output for ASCII values below '0', you'll need a mapping from the integer value (the ASCII number) to the literal, like this:

```
String[] literals0to32 = {"NUL", "SOH", "STX", /* to be continued */ };

private static String toLiteral(int value) {

   if (value < 0 || value > 255)
      throw new IKnowThatIHaveToValidateParametersException();

   if (value < 32) 
     return literals0To32[value];
   else
     return (char) value;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how about when my prof. enter the number 0 it'll print nul.?

Comment: No, in that case it will print something undefined. Editing my answer for a quick solution (fragment) for ASCII

Comment: can you edit again by putting all the codes starts in public class. please.

Comment: @jhoanne - of course ... not. ;) You've already accepted another answer and I already provided too much help for something that smells like homework. I'm not creating a copy'n'paste solution.

Comment: sorry for that ;( thanks for giving me your info. it really helps me. but it is not my homework. sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the corresponding [Unicode Control Pictures](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf), e.g. `\u2400` for ␀ (`nul`).

Answer (score -1):

```
class prg1{
    public static void main(char a){
        int b=(int)a;
        System.out.println("ASCII value ="+b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "a";
    char b = a.charAt(0);
    int c = b;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```